# IFrame element tooltip does not overflow the iframe container

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an issue with iframe elements overflow, which is the following:

I have an element that is a child for iframe and by hovering on this element there is a tooltip appears, but this tooltip does not overflow the iframe container,
[Open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YExA1.png)
I know that the browser already force iframe elements to not overflow for security reasons, but is there any workaround for this issue ?
Also I tried to use element title attribute and this works fine and overflowed, but its design could not be styled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iframe's have their own window and you can not overflow them into the parent window

Comment: I already know this, and this makes me asks for workaround tor this issue

Comment: You could use postMessage API to communicate with parent window and show something there instead of in the iframe

Comment: Unfortunately iframe used in some library that I use, I did not make it native by myself

Comment: Don't know any workarounds for it then.